# Is there a Stack Exchange site for questions regarding management?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange site for questions regarding management, both of people and resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions) site in public beta, so if your questions are related to managing projects you can ask there.  If you search [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) you'll find several other management sites proposed.